# ¿Cómo puedo decorar "document.write" con CSS?

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero Decorar el Texto que se Imprime en el Documento con JS, Quiero Decorar Específicamente el Elemento Impreso, Por Separado.

PD : Soy Nuevo con JavaScript si cometí algún **Error** Informen Por Favor.

```js
var nombre = prompt('Ingrese su Nombre :');
var edad = prompt('Dígite su Edad :');
var cancion = prompt('¿Cúal es su Canción Favorita?'); 

alert('Hola Bienvenido : ' + nombre);

// Imprimir Datos //

document.write("Se ha Registrado como : " + nombre + "<br/>Su Edad es : " + edad + '<br/>Su Canción Favorita es : ' + cancion);
```

```css
/* ??? */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="script" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="titulo">Datos Obtenidos : </h1>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rikpR5zyFFgekOfmIwlqM7chKu8KwUKS/view"><br/><input type="button" value="Ver Código Fuente"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿cuál elemento impreso el nombre?

Answer (score 1):

Agregale una clase al texto e inserta todo el mensaje dentro de una etiqueta, puede ser `<p>`, `<span>`,etc. En mi caso use `<p>` y le puse `simple-text` como clase pero es arbitrario, puedes ponerle el nombre que quieras.

```js
var nombre = prompt('Ingrese su Nombre :');
var edad = prompt('Dígite su Edad :');
var cancion = prompt('¿Cúal es su Canción Favorita?'); 

alert('Hola Bienvenido : ' + nombre);

// Imprimir Datos //

document.write("<p class='simple-text'>Se ha Registrado como : " + nombre + "<br/>Su Edad es : " + edad + '<br/>Su Canción Favorita es : ' + cancion+"</p>");
```

```css
.simple-text {
  color: red
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="script" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="titulo">Datos Obtenidos : </h1>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rikpR5zyFFgekOfmIwlqM7chKu8KwUKS/view"><br/><input type="button" value="Ver Código Fuente"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```